# Getting various errors using dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

```
SET @SQLSTATEMENT = 'INSERT INTO #MAX_STORAGE
                        SELECT MAX(A.[ROW]) 
                        FROM
                            (SELECT * 
                             FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[Refined_Est_Probability_09_MODIFIED] 
                             WHERE 
                                 [FIPST_ENT] = ' + @FIPST_ENT + ' 
                                 AND [FIPCNTY_ENT] = ' + @FIPCNTY_ENT + '
                                 AND [SIC_ENT] = ' + @SIC2_ENT + '
                                 AND [FMSZ_ENT] = ' + @FMSZENT_ENT + '
                                 AND [ESTABLISHMENTS_AVAILABLE_FMSZEST <= ' + @MAXIMUM_FMSZEST+'] > 0) A'

EXEC(@SQLSTATEMENT)
```

I was running the dynamic SQL query above as part of a stored procedure I had written and got the following error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Invalid column name 'A'.

I then changed my query so that it looked like this (eliminated the alias `A`):

```
SET @SQLSTATEMENT =
    'INSERT INTO #MAX_STORAGE
        SELECT 
           MAX([ROW]) 
        FROM
           (SELECT * 
            FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[Refined_Est_Probability_09_MODIFIED] 
            WHERE [FIPST_ENT] = ' + @FIPST_ENT + ' 
              AND [FIPCNTY_ENT] = ' + @FIPCNTY_ENT + '
              AND [SIC_ENT] = ' + @SIC2_ENT + '
              AND [FMSZ_ENT] = ' + @FMSZENT_ENT + '
              AND [ESTABLISHMENTS_AVAILABLE_FMSZEST <= ' + @MAXIMUM_FMSZEST + '] > 0)'

EXEC(@SQLSTATEMENT)
```

But I still ran into an error (this time different):

> Msg 102, level 15, state 1, line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'

I declared the following variables earlier in the procedure with their respective data types/lengths seen next to them:

- @FIPST_ENT CHAR(2)
- @FIPCNTY_ENT CHAR(3)
- @SIC2_ENT CHAR(2)
- @FMSZENT_ENT CHAR(1)
- @MAXIMUM_FMSZENT CHAR(1)
- @SQLSTATEMENT VARCHAR(MAX)

Before this dynamic SQL statement was reached in the stored procedure, the temporary table `#MAX_STORAGE` was already created and contains only one column of datatype `int`.

Am I missing something I'm doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: does it work if you put hard coded values in for the variables?  DOes just the inner query work?  Does just the middle select (everythihng but insert).

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Yeah it does work with hard coded values in place of the variables. I had tested that before. I'm starting to think this isn't where the issue is with my procedure! I'll keep searching

Comment: This line looks odd:  `AND [ESTABLISHMENTS_AVAILABLE_FMSZEST<='+@MAXIMUM_FMSZEST+'] > 0)'` do you have column names with a `<=` in them?

Comment: @DStanley I have a few columns in my table that have different `@MAXIMUM_FMSZEST` values (ranging from 1-9, A-C). That's why I needed dynamic SQL because that column changes every iteration depending on what the `@MAXIMUM_FMSZEST` value is. Thus, if `@MAXIMUM_FMSZEST` = 9, the column I want to be greater than 0 would be `[ESTABLISHMENTS_AVAILABLE_FMSZEST<=9]`. But to answer your question, yes the `<=` part is in the column name.

Comment: Could any of the values passed in have a `)` or other control characters in them?  `;`, `--`, etc.?

Comment: @DStanley None of those kinds of characters. Everything is either letters or numbers (one or the other)

Comment: Are the values for the 4 variables that are in the WHERE clause (not including `@MAXIMUM_FMSZEST`) numeric only or are some alphanumeric? Because those values are not enclosed in single-quotes within the dynamic SQL.

Comment: Actually, rather than guessing, do a `PRINT @SQLSTATEMENT` to see what is wrong ;-)

Comment: @srutzky `FIPST_ENT` is numeric in nature (i.e. 01-50) but cast as a character. Likewise with the other `FIPCNTY_ENT` and `SIC2_ENT`. `FMSZENT` is cast as a character but is sometimes numeric (i.e. 1-9) and  other times non-numeric (i.e. A-C).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At bare minimum, you need to enclose string fields in escaped-single-quotes within the Dynamic SQL. The adaptation I show below is based on this comment on the Question:

> `FIPST_ENT` is numeric in nature (i.e. 01-50) but cast as a character. Likewise with the other `FIPCNTY_ENT` and `SIC2_ENT`. `FMSZENT` is cast as a character but is sometimes numeric (i.e. 1-9) and other times non-numeric (i.e. A-C).

So it seems that only `FMSZENT` needs the escaped-single-quotes.

Also, using a derived query requires an alias. So whatever the initial problem was, you then introduced a new parse error by removing the alias ;-).

```
SET @SQLSTATEMENT =

'INSERT INTO #MAX_STORAGE
SELECT MAX(tmp.[ROW]) FROM

(SELECT * FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[Refined_Est_Probability_09_MODIFIED] 
WHERE [FIPST_ENT] = '+@FIPST_ENT+' 
AND [FIPCNTY_ENT] = '+@FIPCNTY_ENT+'
AND [SIC_ENT] = '+@SIC2_ENT+'
AND [FMSZ_ENT] = '''+@FMSZENT_ENT+'''
AND [ESTABLISHMENTS_AVAILABLE_FMSZEST<='+@MAXIMUM_FMSZEST+'] > 0) tmp;'
```

Now, when it comes to debugging Dynamic SQL, the first step should be looking at what SQL you actually constructed, as it might not be what you think it should be:

```
PRINT @SQLSTATEMENT;
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. I prefer using CHAR(39) though instead of a bunch of apostrophes in a row. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ultimate8 : you are welcome. And regarding CHAR(39) vs double-single-quote, yeah, I have seen a few people do that. I am so used to the double-single quote that I never remember about CHAR(39), but certainly nothing wrong with it, and yes, it does improve readability :).

Comment: my only remaining question is **why** do you need to enclose `@FMSZENT_ENT` but not anything else when all of the variables (`@FIPST_ENT`, `@FIPCNTY_ENT`, and `@SIC2_ENT`, and even `@FMSZENT_ENT`) are all defined as char type. Is it because `@FMSZENT_ENT` is unlike the others and has non-numeric values in it?

Comment: @ultimate8 : Essentially yes. Be careful to not confuse the two layers of what you are doing. The outer layer (so to speak) is the dynamic SQL string. Any variables that you use to concatenate into the `@SQLSTATEMENT` string need to likewise be strings because you can just add an INT or DATETIME value to a VARCHAR. If your other variables were INT datatypes, you would have to use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @Variable)` in order to concatenate them in. The inner layer is the query being executed, and `AND [FMSZ_ENT] = A` is not valid since `A` is a string and needs to be in quotes.